# Dynamically remove row and update indices

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where a user can add a row of information:

```
   <div id="refItem">
    FirstName 
    LastName
   </div>
```

users can keep pressing the add button and it will then keep appending to that div another row of data by manipulating the DOM. It also updates the ViewModel collection indices too. The ViewModel contains a collection of  which has, FirstName and LastName as above

When the View loads, it uses the Model to render the data as above (so imagine a for loop rendering the row of data)

Question:

How can I delete the row from client side and update the indices at the same time before the user hits the submit button? what JQuery do I need to get hold of the row to delete and then update the DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your exact markup, but in general:

- use `$(selector).remove()` to delete the row
- loop through the items and use `$(this).prop("name", "value")` to update the index.

Here's an example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ppg2/3/))

```
function del(index) {
    var toDelete = $("#refItem"+index);
    toDelete.remove();

    var id=1;
    // select all elements with id starting with "refItem", and loop
    $("div[id^=refItem]").each(function(item) {
        // update the "id" properties
        $(this).prop("id", "refItem"+id++);
    });
}
```

As an alternative, you could also put a button in each row, and remove it using a relative selector like `(this).parent().remove()`.  ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bSg9/2/)).

Comment: Thanks. looks promising but now trying to figure out how to update the indices of the model collection being bound. This is my structure really: Text (FirstName), Select (for things like relationship type) and another Text (LastName). So these are indexes and when you press "add", it creates it in that same format by taking the last item and adding 1 to it. But with the code supplied to remove, how would I go through the items and update the indice?

Comment: also because the add button is being added from clientside, how can I wire up the delete button to call the jquery on click function? ($("input:button[name='Delete']").on("click", function() {...)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas the "index" is a property of the model?  If so, then you need to add it to the form, right?  You'll need something like `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Index)`.  Here's an example of how it should look on the client side: http://jsfiddle.net/VKYJp/1/.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas as far as wiring up the handler, you can just put the wireup code anywhere in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` block.

Comment: thanks. I pretty much figured it out. probably the most inefficient way but it works. Basically after removing, I did a find for the elements in the current div it is iterating through where the name attribute of the text/select inputs ends in a certain phrase. I then change its Id and Name attribute to "correct" the index